# How to prevent datatable from overlapping other elements when zoomed in

Tags: css, datatable, overlap

I have a datatable and a sidebar menu. The positioning of the elements looks okay when the zoom is at 100%, however, when it's zoomed in to 110%, the datatable overlaps with my sidebar menu.

I tried using 'overflow' property but it doesn't work. Any other ways to prevent the elements from overlapping each other?

Answer (score 0):

it would be better if you provided your code . But your prolem might be solved by using width and height in terms of vertical height(vh) and horizontal width it'll stay constant on every screen size. hope this solves your issue